# Arabic characters appears reversed - access DB2 AS400 using ORACLE gateway ODBC

Tags: oracle, ibm-midrange, gateway, db2-400, nls-lang

I'm trying to access DB2 on AS400 from oracle database using oracle gateway for ODBC.

I'm using the IBM i Access for windows as ODBC driver.

my initdg4odbc.ini gateway configuration is:

```
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = DSN_name
HS_LANGUAGE=ARABIC_AMERICA.AR8MSWIN1256
```

Database character set is :  `ARABIC_AMERICA.AR8MSWIN1256`

when I query column  with Arabic characters it  returns in reversed order:

[image: [a][https://i.stack.imgur.com/yia6P.png]

any suggestions please?

thanks

Comment: Did you try other clients? It could be a limitation of IBM i Access. Did you set `NLS_LANG` at your client machine?

Comment: im using the same IBM i Access with Excel and its retrieves Arabic characters correctly .i aslo checked the NLS_LAN on my Linux machine and its correct  ARABIC_AMERICA.AR8MSWIN1256.